# Merging Excel workbooks into a single workbook using Mathematica

Tags: export, excel

I have several Excel workbooks (in *.xlsx format) that I wish to merge into a single new workbook.
The data in the workbooks have exactly the same format; they contain tables similar to this one:
[image: workbook:] 
I'm using:

```
 setDir := 
 Quiet@Check[SetDirectory@DirectoryName@$InputFileName, 
 SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]]

 setDir
```

Next; the following command merges the content of the workbooks into a single conglomerate:

```
xlsxData = TableForm[Import[setDir, {"Directory", "*.xlsx"}]];
```

But, when I attempt the following:

```
Export["Output.xlsx", xlsxData, "XLSX"]
```

the output workbook doesn't contain tables.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use TableForm.

Comment: If I don't use TableForm the data is disbursed into many worksheets

Comment: If you are trying to combine info from multiple spreadsheets onto one spreadsheet, use `Join[]` instead of `TableForm`.

Comment: When I use Join, the 70 workbooks are exported to 70 corresponding worksheets; contained in a single workbook. What I'm attempting instead is to export the 70 workbooks into a single worksheet within a workbook.  Thank you.

Comment: When I use: xlsxData = TableForm[Import[setDir, {"Directory", "*.xlsx"}]]   I can see that all the tables are imported correctly into Mathematica as a single (vertical) array.  The problem resides in exporting this array into a single worksheet within an Excel workbook.

Comment: setDir := 
 Quiet@Check[SetDirectory@DirectoryName@$InputFileName, 
   SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]]

xlsxData = TableForm[Import[setDir, {"Directory", "*.xlsx"}]];

Length[xlsxData]  gives 1.

So; I do:

Output = Table[xlsxData[[1]][[i]], {i, 1, 70}];

Export["Output.xlsx", "Model Tables" -> Output] 

Unfortunately; the result of the above evaluations is that the 70 workbooks are exported as rows (instead of as tables) in 
a worksheet called "Model Tables" contained in the workbook
Output.xlsx. What I'm I missing?