# Merging Excel workbooks into a single workbook using Mathematica (Redux)

Tags: export, excel

In reference to:
"[Merging Excel workbooks into a single workbook using Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138565/merging-excel-workbooks-into-a-single-workbook-using-mathematica)" the only solution that has worked for me so far is:
`setDir:=Quiet@Check[SetDirectory@DirectoryName@$InputFileName, SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]]
 xlsxData = Import[setDir, {"Directory", "*.xlsx"}];
table1 = Table[xlsxData[[1]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table2 = Table[xlsxData[[2]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table3 = Table[xlsxData[[3]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table4 = Table[xlsxData[[4]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table5 = Table[xlsxData[[5]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table6 = Table[xlsxData[[6]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table7 = Table[xlsxData[[7]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table8 = Table[xlsxData[[8]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table9 = Table[xlsxData[[9]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table10 = Table[xlsxData[[10]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table11 = Table[xlsxData[[11]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table12 = Table[xlsxData[[12]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table13 = Table[xlsxData[[13]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table14 = Table[xlsxData[[14]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table15 = Table[xlsxData[[15]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table16 = Table[xlsxData[[16]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table17 = Table[xlsxData[[17]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table18 = Table[xlsxData[[18]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table19 = Table[xlsxData[[19]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table20 = Table[xlsxData[[20]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table21 = Table[xlsxData[[21]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table22 = Table[xlsxData[[22]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table23 = Table[xlsxData[[23]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table24 = Table[xlsxData[[24]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table25 = Table[xlsxData[[25]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table26 = Table[xlsxData[[26]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table27 = Table[xlsxData[[27]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table28 = Table[xlsxData[[28]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table29 = Table[xlsxData[[29]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table30 = Table[xlsxData[[30]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table31 = Table[xlsxData[[31]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table32 = Table[xlsxData[[32]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table33 = Table[xlsxData[[33]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table34 = Table[xlsxData[[34]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table35 = Table[xlsxData[[35]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table36 = Table[xlsxData[[36]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table37 = Table[xlsxData[[37]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table38 = Table[xlsxData[[38]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table39 = Table[xlsxData[[39]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table40 = Table[xlsxData[[40]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table41 = Table[xlsxData[[41]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table42 = Table[xlsxData[[42]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table43 = Table[xlsxData[[43]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table44 = Table[xlsxData[[44]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table45 = Table[xlsxData[[45]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table46 = Table[xlsxData[[46]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table47 = Table[xlsxData[[47]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table48 = Table[xlsxData[[48]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table49 = Table[xlsxData[[49]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table50 = Table[xlsxData[[50]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table51 = Table[xlsxData[[51]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table52 = Table[xlsxData[[52]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table53 = Table[xlsxData[[53]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table54 = Table[xlsxData[[54]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table55 = Table[xlsxData[[55]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table56 = Table[xlsxData[[56]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table57 = Table[xlsxData[[57]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table58 = Table[xlsxData[[58]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table59 = Table[xlsxData[[59]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table60 = Table[xlsxData[[60]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table61 = Table[xlsxData[[61]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table62 = Table[xlsxData[[62]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table63 = Table[xlsxData[[63]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table64 = Table[xlsxData[[64]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table65 = Table[xlsxData[[65]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table66 = Table[xlsxData[[66]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table67 = Table[xlsxData[[67]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table68 = Table[xlsxData[[68]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table69 = Table[xlsxData[[69]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table70 = Table[xlsxData[[70]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

table71 = Table[xlsxData[[71]][[1]][[j]], {j, 1, 8}];

Output = Join[table1, table2, table3, table4, table5, table6, table7, 
   table8, table9, table10, table11, table12, table13, table14, 
   table15, table16, table17, table18, table19, table20, table21, 
   table22, table23, table24, table25, table26, table27, table28, 
   table29, table30, table31, table32, table33, table34, table35, 
   table36, table37, table38, table39, table40, table41, table42, 
   table43, table44, table45, table46, table47, table48, table49, 
   table50, table51, table52, table53, table54, table55, table56, 
   table57, table58, table59, table60, table61, table62, table63, 
   table64, table65, table66, table67, table68, table69, table70, 
   table71];
`
Dimensions[Output] gives {568,8}                                            which is correct and                                                        Export["Output.xlsx", "Model Tables" -> Output]                             gives the correct output.  My question is: How can I avoid having to do the above monstrosity? Thank you.

Comment: Try `output = Table[xlsxData[[n, 1, j]], {n, 71}, {j, 8}] // Join`

Comment: or `output = Join @ xlsxData[[ ;; 71, 1, ;; 8]]`

Comment: Bob; your Output array has dimensions {71,8,8} and this is exactly the problem that I was running into.  Edmund; your Output array has dimensions {568,8} which when exported gives the correct workbook containing all the 71 tables.  Thank you both for replying to my "SOS" and  I'm glad this is settled at last (with your help!) :-)